# Windows 7 bluetooth audio suddenly not working after Windows update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, bluetooth

Windows 7 64 bits
Bluetooth audio worked fine but suddenly not working after Windows update on June / July 2016.

The `listen to music` is not clickable in `Devices and printers`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intel compatibility issue on Microsoft KB 3161608/3172605 updates on June / July 2016. More information please check this [link](https://communities.intel.com/thread/103579)

New intel PROset/bluetooth [driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26311/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-Software-for-Windows-7-?v=t)

Credit to: Aur Saraf's comment from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/471767/bluetooth-headset-pairs-and-appears-in-sound-devices-but-shows-as-disconnected)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!