# Bluetooth Headset/SoundBar paired but in Sound Devices it shows as Disconnected

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, connection

I had no answer option on the bellow post, in the same time none of the provided solutions worked for me.

[Bluetooth Headset pairs and appears in Sound Devices, but shows as Disconnected?](https://superuser.com/questions/471767/bluetooth-headset-pairs-and-appears-in-sound-devices-but-shows-as-disconnected?answertab=votes#tab-top)

For my LG Sound Bar, the issue was caused by: Bluetooth Absolute Volume

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/151957-how-enable-disable-bluetooth-absolute-volume-windows-10-a.html

All I had to do was:

1. Removed the device.
2. I have opened the Command Prompt as admin & run bellow command:

   reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT /v DisableAbsoluteVolume /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
3. Added the device again and started to play :)

Source:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-bluetooth-to-lg-soundbar-not-working/4c2d45d0-981b-464d-9d55-ae01b0c8687d?rtAction=1609512354662&page=19

Answer (score 0):

I know you answered it already but for anyone searching for this. There is another similar thread on superuser which has many things to try. I wanted to add 1 more but it was locked. So I will put it here.

Make sure the Service is enabled: Bluetooth Audio Gateway Service